# Como adicionar um popup com imagem ao acessar o site

Tags: javascript, html, popup

Gostaria de fazer um popup parecido com esse da [Kabum](http://www.kabum.com.br/), porém sem um formulário, só com uma imagem e a opção de fechar.

Procurei e achei esse código:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', 'Pagina', 'STATUS=NO, TOOLBAR=NO, LOCATION=NO, DIRECTORIES=NO, RESISABLE=NO, SCROLLBARS=YES, TOP=10, LEFT=10, WIDTH=770, HEIGHT=400');">Clique para abrir a janela POP-up</a>
```

Porém abre uma página nova e preciso que ele fique no mesmo site como o do exemplo da Kabum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não consegui visualizar o popup do kabum, mas pelo que entendi na sua pergunta você pretende fazer algo como:

```js
var close = document.getElementById('close');
var popup = document.getElementById('popup');

close.addEventListener("click", function() {
  popup.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#popup {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 2px #000;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#close {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #cc0033;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup" class="popup">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" alt="popup">
  <div>
    <button id="close">Sair</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/sso0fyxr/3/)